# call custom Java method from jrxml passing the parent object reference

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Can I invoke a some Java method from expression element in jrxml that can pass a "reference" to this element (from which it was called)?

Some pseudo code:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="3" width="74" height="16">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[UtilCheck.getval(_this)==true]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Primary value"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

In Java the the signature of such method will be like this:

```
class UtilCheck{
  public static boolean getval(JRDesignTextField texfield) {
   //here i need change the value of some of the text field attributes. 
    //or get accesss to it parent node 
    //or modify its parent attribute
  }
}
```

I want to modify this element's attributes on the fly or access parent elements and so on.

Comment: It is not working in this way. You can try to use *JasperReports API* or libraries over *JasperReports*

Comment: You can also check *[Scriptlets](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/scriptlet/)* abilities - maybe this feature helps you to solve your tasks

Comment: i tried using scriptlets however not able to get access to element for which i want to change width am i missing something. Thanks